# SQL Insert or Update

Tags: php, sql

Есть ли какая-нибудь функция, которая добавляла бы значения в базу данных, если с определённым id значений нет, и обновляла бы, если значение существует. Насколько я понял, надо каждый раз проверять на существование данной строки и потом, если она есть, то выполняем update, а если нет, то insert. Или есть другой вариант, без лишних запросов?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

---

Нет, ну серьезно, в чем понт забивать текст в код?

Comment: В SQL Server для этого имеется оператор MERGE.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ из комментария

---

В MySQL вы можете использовать конструкцию `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE`:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```

Подробнее http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 0):

базу то укажите. для postgres upsert будет выглядеть так

```
UPDATE "SC_Wonder"."TMining_New"
SET "FH_09_Q" = 100,
    "FH_09_Fe" = 20,
    "FH_09_ZnO" = 0,
    "FH_09_S" =0
WHERE "FMineObj_ID" = 7
  AND "FDate" = '2015-01-28' ;
INSERT INTO "SC_Wonder"."TMining_New" ( "FDate",
                                        "FMineObj_ID",
                                        "FH_09_Q",
                                        "FH_09_Fe",
                                        "FH_09_ZnO",
                                        "FH_09_S" )
SELECT '2015-01-28',
       7,
       100,
       20,
       0,
       0
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1
     FROM "SC_Wonder"."TMining_New"
     WHERE "FMineObj_ID" = 7
       AND "FDate" = '2015-01-28');
```